# g++ can't build Hello World

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, iostream

my problem that I simply can't compile Hello World programm with g++

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(void) {

        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiler gave me message:

```
evgeny@debian:~/Documents/Programming$ g++ test.cpp -o test
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/clocale:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/32/bits/c++locale.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/localefwd.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/locale.h:29:25: fatal error: bits/locale.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/locale.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've installed libstdc++-developer, tried to use -I/way-to-the-missing-lib, different architecture keys etc., but it doesn't work as well.

Architecture info
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

OS Debian 8.9

g++ version
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

installed packages list:

```
evgeny@debian:~$ dpkg --list | grep c++                                                                                                                                                          
ii  lib32stdc++-4.9-dev                   4.9.2-10                                   amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)                                                
ii  lib32stdc++6                          4.9.2-10                                   amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (32 bit Version)                                                   
ii  libflac++6:amd64                      1.3.0-3                                    amd64        Free Lossless Audio Codec - C++ runtime library                                                
ii  libgpgme++2                           4:4.14.2-2+deb8u2                          amd64        c++ wrapper library for gpgme                                                                  
ii  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64              2.4.0-1                                    amd64        type-safe Signal Framework for C++ - runtime                                                   
ii  libstdc++-4.9-dev:amd64               4.9.2-10                                   amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)                                                
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                      4.9.2-10                                   amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3                                                                    
ii  libx32stdc++-4.9-dev                  4.9.2-10                                   amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)                                                
ii  libx32stdc++6                         4.9.2-10                                   amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (x32)
```

Any ideas? I hope solution is obvious, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `-m32` today?

Comment: Oh, why everybody paying attention to unsignificant things, I've deleted It, cause It doesn't matter in this case. If you intrested, i comparing assembler lisntings, nothing else

Comment: What version of Debian, what architecture, and what packages have you installed?

Comment: Then please edit your question and tell things that matter, including C++ related packages that you have installed. `build-essential` is for C programs, not C++ ones

Comment: I've added info

Comment: 3.16 is probably your kernel version, not the version of Debian. Debian 3 is from the previous century!

Comment: Yes, it is. I cant add Debian version because Im quite far away from machine now. Can it really affect in some way? I thought I just forgot to install something

Comment: Yes, you forgot to install several things. My answer gives some clues.

Comment: Thank you for hint lol, may be someone will get it

Comment: Use `cat /etc/debian_version` to get your version of Debian

Comment: Question stays unclear since it does not list the C++ related packages which have been installed

Comment: Install build-essentials (it's not just for C programs).

Comment: My debian version is 8.9. build-essentials already installed.

Comment: It looks like you need libc6-dev. It should be already installed but check anyway.

Comment: yes, it installed already

Answer (score 1):

If you use `-m32` (which in 2017 is a strange thing to do, since most Linux are 64 bits), you need 32 bits libraries, such as `lib32stdc++-7-dev` package (or `lib32stdc++-6-dev` ; it depends upon your version of `g++`) on Debian.

BTW, naming your executable `test` is very poor taste, it collides with the standard (perhaps builtin) [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

I recommend compiling for your native architecture (probably x86-64) with all warnings and debug info, e.g. using

```
 g++ -Wall -Wextra -g test.cpp -o mytest
```

and of course, the resulting executable `mytest` is likely to be 64 bits. You could check with the `file mytest` command.

BTW, your `g++` 4.9 is quite old. Why don't you upgrade it? You could install GCC5 or GCC6, e.g. with `aptitude install g++-6`; in october 2017 the current version of GCC is [GCC7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/)

Today you'll better learn at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (don't lose your time learning something older). Older standards are obsolete. So it is better to use at least GCC6 if you want a good support of that standard.

Of course, you need the C++ standard library development package. On my Debian/Sid it is `libstdc++-6-dev`

The `build-essential` metapackage is for building essential utilities coded in  C, not in C++.
 **You need to *explicitly* install several C++ related packages** (and you don't tell which you have installed).

If you know some Debian package coded in C++ (e.g. `fish`), you might use the `aptitude build-dep` command on it; it would install properly all the packages needed to build it, and that would include necessary C++ stuff. So you could try `aptitude build-dep fish`

In october 2017 the [stable version](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/) of Debian is Debian stretch 9.2; if you use an older variant, you should consider upgrading your distribution.

Comment: if I don't use this key or use -m64 i got the same problem. About the test, thank you, never thought about it

Comment: All good points but none that actually attempt to answer the question.

Comment: The OP don't tell enough about his system to get help. BTW, this question  is more a sysadmin question so should go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ with a lot more details (all the packages related to C++ that has been installed)

Comment: I tried `aptitude build-dep fish` but nothing was found and for g++-6 same thing. p.s. all pkg list added to main post. I have Debian 8.9, but I belive it should work without upgrading

Answer (score -2):

Can you find the locale.h file in '/usr/inlcude/bits' directory, the compilation error indicates the file is missing.

Comment: But `/usr/include/bits/` is an *internal* header directory; it is likely to be filled by some `lib32stdc++-6-dev` package